# Real-world examples of searching through data

Tags: search, filter, dropdown, data, examples

Our company collects a user's data and allows the user to explore their data by using various dropdowns. We want to give the user a way to save their filters, like a saved config or saved view (similar to Saved Reports in Google Analytics).

Are there any examples you've seen in the wild where there are two ways to explore data or explore the system - either via searching or filtering (custom) or via a saved view/config. (Ideally examples where the two options are on the same view).

This is our current way of exploring the data:

[image]

And my first thought was to introduce the other option like this, but it doesn't feel super clear to me. (The platform also doesn't have a 'Filter' or 'Search' button currently... as the user selects something from the dropdown, the data updates below.)

[image]

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think [Notion](https://www.notion.so/) does a really good job of handling this. Anyone can filter the view of a page

[image: Notion filters]

After you've created a filter there are a few actions to choose from:

- Reset: discard the filter and return to the default view
- Save for everyone: make the current view the default for everyone else viewing the page
- Save as new view: save this filtered version of the page but don't overwrite the original
- Merge into advanced filter: if you have multiple filters applied, you can combine and save them as an advanced filter

[image: Filter actions]

Check out their [Filters documentation](https://www.notion.so/help/views-filters-and-sorts) for more details